# Не удается правильно спозиционировать блоки в адаптивной сетке

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, позиционирование

Есть бутстраповская сетка. Хочу сделать так, чтобы на больших экранах блок с картинкой располагался справа, а текст слева, а на маленьких разрешениях - картинка уходила вверх, а текст съезжал вниз. Знаю, что этого можно добиться с помощью классов `push-pull`, но почему-то в моем случае блоки не располагаются так, как это должно быть..

[ссылка на фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12597/)

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
 body {
  margin: 10px;
}
.image {
  position: relative;
}
.summary {
  position: static;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-md-push-6 image">
      <img class="profile-pic" src="http://cdn.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/l-Wittle-puppy-yawning.jpg" width="100" height="100" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-md-pull-6 summary">
      <p>this is sparta</p>
      <p>this is sparta</p>
      <p>this is sparta</p>
      <p>this is sparta</p>
      <p>this is sparta</p>
      <p>this is sparta</p>
      <p>this is sparta</p>
      <p>this is sparta</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Один из простых вариантов.

```
.image, .summary {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.image {    
    float: right;
    width: auto;
}
.summary {      
    width: 80%;
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
.image {
    float:left;
}
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12601/

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */

@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
 body {
  margin: 10px;
}
.image,
.summary {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.image {
  float: right;
  width: auto;
}
.summary {
  width: 80%;
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .image {
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-md-push-6 image">
      <img class="profile-pic" src="http://cdn.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/l-Wittle-puppy-yawning.jpg" width="100" height="100" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-md-pull-6 summary">
      <p>this is sparta jigjifdgifdo gig dfi gj dog gidsof gidfjs igdfj ijfds isd io jidfjsg if diosgj idsfo gofidsj gifsoj oidsjg ifdsoj giosdf gidjs ijfdsi fidsgj idofsjg</p>
      <p>this is sparta</p>
      <p>this is sparta</p>
      <p>this is sparta</p>
      <p>this is sparta</p>
      <p>this is sparta</p>
      <p>this is sparta</p>
      <p>this is sparta</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: на самом деле, что-то у вас совсем непонятное получилось - слева вверху зачем-то белая пустота образовалась, а на больших разрешениях картинка вообще куда-то далеко-далеко вправо убегает. Правильное решение - обойти позиционирование static и вопрос решен